# selectize input with multiple values: GET operation results in unnecessarily long URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a filter on my search form that allows people to filter what results are shown by YouTube channels. I do this by using a selectize select input field that allows them to populate the field with the channels they want to limit the results to.

This works great, but the URL when they submit the page ends up unnecessarily long:

```
/search?q=rubber&channels=1&channels=2&channels=3&sort=rel
```

As you can see, the URL repeats the `channel=#` parameter for EACH value. Is there a way that I can condense this to something more similar to:

```
/search?q=rubber&channels=1,2,3&sort=rel
```

I can get the values of the selectize in that format by doing:

```
var channels = $('#channels')[0].selectize.items;
```

Which returns

```
["1","2","3"]
```

But I don't know how to reflect that in the resulting URL when the form is submitted.

I tried the following:

```
    $('#filter-form').on('submit', function(e){
        var tags = $('#tags')[0].selectize.items;
        var channels = $('#channels')[0].selectize.items;

        $('#channels').val(channels.join(','));
    });
```

Which did not seem to do anything.

The selectize field in my form (method="GET"):

```
<select name="channels" id="channels" multiple placeholder="search channels" aria-describedby="channelTip"></select>
```

Comment: Try to change method to POST or create an hidden input to store the array as string.

Comment: @Shim-Sao I want to stick with the GET method so people can share the URLs; however, I like the hidden input approach I didn't think of that. Will try that now, thank you.